# using double arrays to draw a triangle

Tags: java

So I need help using double arrays/matrixes to draw triangles like this:

```
     *     *     *
    ***   ***   ***
   ***** ***** *****
  *******************
```

using matrix and like double arrays.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[][] d = new char[4][7];

    for(int i = 0;i<4;i++){

        for(int j=0;j<7;j++){
            d[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }

    ///


    for(int b = 0;b<4;b++){

        for(int g=0;g<7;g++){

            System.out.print(d[b][g]);
        }
        System.out.println();


}   
}
```

when you run it you get 'nothing' but thats because 
`d[i][j] = ' ';`

please help?

Comment: i got it, thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to draw a triangle, so do it.

```
for(int i = 0;i<4;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<7;j++){
        d[i][j] = (Math.abs(7/2-j)<=i ? '*' : ' ');
    }
}
```

Comment: if i wanted to make it three triangles, how would it work? im just curious

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] d = new char[4][7];

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            d[i][j] = ' ';
        }

        for(int k = 0; k < i+1; k++) {
            d[i][3+k] = '*';
            d[i][3-k] = '*';
        }
    }

    for(int b = 0; b < 4; b++){
        for(int g = 0; g < 7; g++){
            System.out.print(d[b][g]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }   
}
```